# Google Cloud Platform - using mysql instance in one project to another project - connect mysql instance in one project to another project

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Project A -  Running webapp in Flask and Python (with endpoint @app.route .... )

Project B - Running another webapp in Flask and Python (with endpoint @app.route .... )

We have a MySQL (CLOUD SQL) instance in project A in Google Cloud Platform. We are using Unix socket to connect to it and it connects just fine in project A. (all is good in Project A).

However, when we use the same MySQL instance for Project B in GCP ... it gives 2002 - connection refused error.  and (Internal Server Error) on the browser page [as it is not able to connect to DB].

Need help to understand how to connect single MySQL (Cloud SQL) instance in GCP across 2 projects. (in same account)
Note: all these are in same region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your Cloud SQL instance has public IP and you are setting the "CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME" configuration  in your app.yaml for your 2 apps correctly. Because if you are using Private IP in your Cloud SQL instance, this connection will not be possible (unless your Cloud SQL instance resides in a host project and/or you enable import/export custom routes for your Cloud SQL VPC peering, however, to implement this last option you'll need to contact GCP Support).

All that being said, if you use public IP, the only thing that you need to do is to give the App Engine service account of the Project B (it should be similar to "service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER_B]@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com") permissions to connect to Cloud SQL (the most restricted predifined role to accomplish this is the "Cloud SQL Client" role) in the IAM section of Project A.

Comment: Thanks Much for your inputs @Alex Riquelme.